# In Python sharing class instance data and methods between threads but one specific variable

Tags: python, multithreading, class, inheritance, instance

Having an initialized class instance I need to share all this instance data and methods between threads but one variable, to have different results between all threads but taking advantage of the initialized data. I need all class methods from instance pointing to that 'private' variable.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.init_data = self._initialize()   <- same for each thread
        self.a = 0   <- private for each thread 

    def _initialize(self):
        # Get data from db (high cost)

    def calculate_a(self, data):
        # Calculate 'a' result from init_data to private 'a' variable

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):

    # Inheritance? 
    # Pass instance as a init parameter and change somehow 'a' variable pointer? 


a = A()
t1 = ThreadClass(a)
t2 = ThreadClass(a)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.calculate_a(data1)
t2.calculate_a(data2)
t1.a <- some result1
t2.a <- some result2
```

Is that possible? Could someone give me any valid solution?

Comment: You could make `init_data` a class attribute so that it's shared by all the instances.

Comment: I can't modify A class because it's 'pyknow' module. This is a minimified class I used to show the example, but there are a lot of class variables involved, not just init_data.

Comment: Ok. Even though the A class is defined in another module you _could_ probably do what you want by monkey-patching it after you import it. However, it's probably simpler & cleaner to create a new class, as shown in my answer.

Comment: BTW, in your code `init_data` is an instance attribute. Calling it a class variable is a little confusing, because it makes it sound like it's a class attribute. Class attributes are shared by all instances of a class, instance attributes are not shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a new class that inherits from A, and has  the expensive `init_data` as a class attribute. Here's a short demo derived from your code.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_data = self._initialize()   # <- same for each thread
        self.a = 0   # <- private for each thread 

    def _initialize(self):
        # Get data from db (high cost)
        print('_initialize called')
        return 1000

    def calculate_a(self, data):
        # Calculate 'a' result from init_data to private 'a' variable
        self.a += self.init_data + data

class MyA(A):
    # Create a single instance of the original class and store its 
    # init_data as a class attribute of MyA
    init_data = A().init_data

    # Get rid of the inherited  _initialize method
    _initialize = None

    # Override the inherited __init__
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

# Test

b = MyA()
b.calculate_a(10)
print(b.a)
c = MyA()
c.calculate_a(100)
print(c.a)
b.calculate_a(20)
print(b.a)
```

**output**

```
_initialize called
1010
1100
2030
```

As you can see, `A._initialize()` only gets called once, when the `MyA` class is being defined. All instances of `MyA` share the `MyA.init_data`, and any methods of `MyA`, including methods that it inherits from `A`, will use that `MyA.init_data` when `self.init_data` is referenced.

Comment: Can you tell me if class variable (shared across all instances of class), is shared across all threads?

Comment: @variable If the class is in the global scope, then its class attributes are visible in all threads.

Comment: Thanks let me give you an exmaple. In Flask, If I install a package via pip install xyz. Then, import xyz in route.py. Then, in the route fucntion if I assign or mutate a variable in xyz, via xyz.varname.append or xyz.varname=100. Now, this will affect varname in all other user threads? This is very dangerous then isnt it? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: @variable Sorry, I don't know Flask, and I don't understand how your comment is relevant to this answer.